# Paragraph numbering in the margins of a two-column document?

Tags: numbering, paragraphs, multicol, marginnote

I've been trying to get paragraph numbers to sit in the margins of a two-column document. I can't get `marginpar` to print any text in the margins at all. When I use `marginnote`, I get an error saying `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255]`.

I have no idea what's going wrong. A couple days ago I was able to get `marginnote` to at least print in the margin, even though it printed over the text of the second column. If I can at least find a way to get `marginnote` to print in the margins, I have absolutely no problem adjusting the style of the document to have a wider center margin so the numbers could rest there.

Is there something I'm obviously doing wrong with `marginnote` to get this error?

In my sample code, I changed `...\marginnote{\pn}...` to `...\marginpar{\pn}...` to show that it doesn't print anything. It won't even compile the document with `marginnote`. Here's the sample code I have now:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\setlength\parindent{0cm}

\newcounter{pc}
\newcommand{\pn}{\bfseries\thepc}   
\newenvironment{pns}{
    \par
    \everypar{\noindent\stepcounter{pc}\leavevmode{\color{red}\marginpar{\pn}\hspace{1.5em}}}
    \setcounter{pc}{0}
}{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{pns}
    \lipsum[1]

    \lipsum[2]

    \lipsum[3]

    \lipsum[4]

    \lipsum[5]

    \lipsum[6]

    \lipsum[7]

    \lipsum[8]

    \lipsum[9]

    \lipsum[10]
    \end{pns}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `\llap` instead of `\marginpar` does the trick, without even loading `marginnote`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setlength\parindent{0cm}
\setlength\columnsep{30pt}
\newcounter{pc}
\newcommand{\pn}{\bfseries\thepc}
\newenvironment{pns}{%
  \par \setcounter{pc}{0}
    \everypar{\noindent\stepcounter{pc}\leavevmode{\color{red}\llap{\pn\hskip0.75em}}%
}}{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{pns}
    \lipsum[1]

    \lipsum[2]

    \lipsum[3]

    \lipsum[4]
    \lipsum[5]
    \end{pns}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]